# Removing integers from int[] array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like some help in getting this program to work. The user must first input upper and lower bounds for the int[] array. Next, they input what numbers to exclude from said array and display. I'm having trouble getting/understanding how to remove these numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first integer for the lower bound now");
        int lower = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Uses user input for lower array bound
        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the second integer for the upper bound");
        int upper = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Uses user input for upper array bound
        Console.WriteLine("Finally, enter the integers you do not want to see in the range");
        int[] exNums = new int[] {int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) }; //User enters number to exclude from range 

        int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(lower, upper).ToArray();
        Random r = new Random();
        int range = 0;

        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {

                    range = r.Next(lower, upper);
                    Console.Write(range + ",");

            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Upper bound cannot be lower than lower bound");
        }
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` takes a starting number _and a number of entries to create_, not the upper bound.

Comment: Why not jsut use a List<int>? You obviously need a variable size, adding and removal. So that is the droid you should be looking for.

Comment: Its probably homework. At least for me, my professors did not have us use Lists or LINQ or anything like that because it abstracts away a lot of good beginner stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upper bound cannot be lower than lower bound");
}
```

Alright. Please, PLEASE don't write code like this. Rather than searching for an exception, check the values yourself.

```
if (upper < lower)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Upper bound cannot be lower than lower bound");
    return;
}
```

---

Let's correctly generate the `IEnumerable<int>` of numbers to start with. `Enumerable.Range` takes a starting number and an entry count, not the upper bounds.

```
IEnumerable<int> allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(lower, (upper - lower) + 1);
```

Assuming we have a collection of numbers to exclude:

```
int[] numbersToExclude = ...;
```

We can simply use the `.Except()` method of LINQ to take out what we don't want.

```
IEnumerable<int> filteredNumbers = allNumbers.Except(numbersToExclude);
```

`.ToArray()`, `.ToList()`, or `foreach` the results of `filteredNumbers` as you wish afterwards.

---

Just in case there is so miscommunication from the question title, "Removing integers from int[] array", you cannot remove entries from a c# array. Once you set the size of an array (the number of items that array can hold) you cannot change it.

The only way to add and remove items from an array is to create an entirely new array and copy over the elements you want to keep.

There are, however, different data structures that *can* add and remove entries without all this data management on your end, most popular is `List<>`.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe there's some reason you need to use Arrays rather than Lists but why not something like... (Java example)

```
int[] answers = new int[upper];
int index=0;
for (int lower; lower<=upper; lower++){
  // if current value is within excluded numbers array, skip
  if (Arrays.binarySearch(excludes, lower) >= 0){
    continue;
  }
  else{
   //add to the answers array
   answers[index] = lower;
   index++;
  }
}
```